# <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/loader.svg"> OR <img src="images/loader.svg" alt="" /> both are Not animating in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, object, svg

**i used both tag but both not working for iphone mean svg not animating in iphone**

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/loader.svg">
```

OR

```
<img src="images/loader.svg" alt="" />
```

Comment: What kind of animation are you using. We're going to need to see the loader.svg (or at least an [mcve] of something that doesn't animate).

Comment: like recycle arrows as a preloader , condition should be a SVG image.